# best way to handle many forks (and "sub-forks") with Github?

Tags: git, version-control, github

My specific example is the Silex repository.

So, just the https://github.com/fabpot/Silex/tree/master/vendor/Symfony/Component part is relating to a ton of other projects (all on the symfony account).

I know that I could manually just fork each of them (but please notice that there's also other vendor projects in the directory above Symfony in last link) and then clone them, set the upstream and fetch it. I guess that could work? I don't know.

Thing is, when I clone (git clone git@github.com/myusername/proj.git) I don't really get all the code. It's the first time I actually want to use github relating my code to other projects and I'm failing to do so.

I followed the instructions at http://help.github.com/fork-a-repo/ but it just feels like I'm doing extra work than what I should be doing. I actually expected to just pull it from the Silex project and get all the code from all the sub-projects Silex is taking code from (in a recursive way, you could say), but it doesn't.

What's the best way to do so? Thanks a lot for the help and I will elaborate more if necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All those folders with a green arrow are submodules.

When you cloned this repo, try `git submodule update --init --recursive`. That will download all the submodules in place.

Note that you can also add the `--recursive` option to the `git clone` command to check them out immediately.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have no editing priviledges, so it would be great if you just changed "--update" to "update". I didn't know about the existance of submodules. Great thing :)